# How to use SP.UI.ModalDialog on plain old HTML page

Tags: modal-dialog, html

I have a plain HTML page (not aspx) that is hosted in my Sharepoint site Assets. Below is the source.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <button type=button onclick="openDialog()">click me</button>
    <div style="display:none">
       <div id="d10">my dialog message</div>
    </div>
    <script>
    function openDialog() {
       var e = document.getElementById('d10');
       var options = {
        title: "My Dialog Title",
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        html: e
       };
       SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I click the button I get an error in the console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: SP is not defined
```

I also tried to lazy load the sp.js using this code...

```
try {
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
catch (error) {
   ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ITSP.TaskForm.InitialisePage, "sp.ui.dialog.js");
   SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}
```

But then I just get a different error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded is not defined
```

Apparently I am missing some `<script src=???>` tags in my HTML file. What do I need to include to make this work?

Comment: I've tried it and had the same result. SP.UI only works within a SharePoint page.

Comment: such a pity. i'll use JQuery-UI dialog if i must.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a minimal HTML file that will make use of SP.UI.ModalDialog:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/corev15.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/msajaxbundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/1033/sp.res.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.init.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/core.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type=button onclick="openDialog()">click me</button>
        <div style="display:none">
           <div id="d10">my dialog message</div>
        </div>
        <script>
        function openDialog() {
           var e = document.getElementById('d10');
           var options = {
            title: "My Dialog Title",
            width: 400,
            height: 300,
            html: e
           };
           SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This one will work for SharePoint Online, can't say anything about on-premises but I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

Update to make it a proper answer:
You can copy all the script tags + the core15.css style tag from the source view of a normal SharePoint page to your HTML file. Once that's done you can delete the tags one by one (when it throws an error after removing a tag, add it back) until you get to the bare minimum that is required to render the modal dialog.

For SharePoint Online the code above seems to be the minimum.

### UPDATE

In my SharePoint 2013 on-premises environment the code below seems to be the minimum required:

(you might have to adjust the long alphanumeric string behind *ScriptResource.axd?d=* to the appropriate value in your environment)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/corev15.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=UpqI01Xk841N_9CuQ5wMNuq9zFYl9ThRGFK83kTirNaZpHlB_KtqOQsuq_rvbhkEoKzWx2eHmGUEVuRsRgkhBYN6G4P88iQ7E9317tHeeWCm7WNLlm-efogSztGRwHF4ALZSZgIi48GJ_F2nixLvqYT_d6nONKgdtAa-ZCAL7pf2SnblS9VJ1CfY9irxg7Kw0&amp;t=ffffffffeea0dba9"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.init.js"></script>                                                       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js"></script>                                                        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/ScriptResx.ashx?name=sp.res&culture=en-us"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type=button onclick="openDialog()">click me</button>
        <div style="display:none">
           <div id="d10">my dialog message</div>
        </div>
        <script>
        function openDialog() {
           var e = document.getElementById('d10');
           var options = {
            title: "My Dialog Title",
            width: 400,
            height: 300,
            html: e
           };
           SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Update 2

And you should change the line

```
html: e
```

to

```
html: e.cloneNode(true)
```

Otherwise the button will only work properly once since you pass the HTML by reference and will be deleted when you close the modal dialog.

Comment: I'm on-premises. It didn't work for me. I got 404 "not found" on the msajaxbundle and sp.res.js. Followed by error "Type is not defined" in the sp.init.js. ... How did you discover this? is it documented somewhere?

Comment: In that case you have to try to find the on-premises equivalents to those files. I stared with the blank HTML page and then just added all the script-tags + the core15.css style tag from the source view of a normal sharepoint page. Then I started removing tags until I got to the bare minimum that is required to render the modal dialog.

Comment: @JohnHenckel 2010 or 2013?

Comment: I am using SP 2013

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: THANKS!!!  Your **Update** works! I had to change the gobbly gook after the ScriptResource to be `d=sn5Brcv_c3hjTK2Q13etWH_zsopxzQDqtCsph....&t=5f9d5645` which I discovered with **View Source** on another sharepoint page of our site.

Comment: @DanielStölzner Thanks a ton! Update #2 i.e. using e.CloneNode(true) was the exact solution I was looking for!

Comment: I tried this and I still get openDialog is not defined