# Why does SharePoint 2013 modal add "?IsDlg=1" to querystring

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, modal-dialog

I am trying to create a modal that generates off of a link.  When the link is clicked, the modal pops-up but I get the error, "An unexpected error has occurred".  When I dive deeper, I find out that SharePoint has appended '?IsDlg=1' to the URL, which causes it to error out. How can I fix this issue?  Code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//User Defined Function to Open Dialog Framework
function OpenDialog(strPageURL)
{

 var dialogOptions = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
 alert(dialogOptions);
 dialogOptions.url = strPageURL;// URL of the Page
 dialogOptions.title = 'Welcome to SharePoint'
 dialogOptions.allowMaximize= true
 dialogOptions.width = 950; // Width of the Dialog
 dialogOptions.height = 500; // Height of the Dialog
 dialogOptions.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate( null, 
 CloseCallback); // Function to capture dialog closed event
 SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(dialogOptions); // Open the Dialog
 return false;
}


function CloseCallback(strReturnValue, target)
{
 if (strReturnValue === SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) // Perform action on Ok.
{
alert("User clicked Ok!");
}
if (strReturnValue === SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) // Perform action on 
Cancel.
{
alert( "User clicked Cancel!");
}
}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<a onclick="OpenDialog('../SitePages/vueCarausel.aspx');">open dialog</a>​

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

'?IsDlg=1' is how SharePoint knows to display a page as a dialog box. With this in the query string, the master page hides all non-form data such as the site icon, title, toplink bar and Quick Launch. To see the impact of '?IsDlg=1', go to a list or library page and note the normal page layout. Append '?IsDlg=1' to the URL and note the changes.

So, I don't think '?IsDlg=1' is the cause of your error. It is what generates the standard SharePoint dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a Modal Dialog, I believe SharePoint appends "?IsDlg=1" to the end of the URL to strip out the layout content. I've seen that error appear when we add the "?IsDlg=1" to the end of any SitePage.

Is it possible to have a page created that is using a page layout, and initiate it from that page? Generally, these are publishing pages, web part pages, or forms (NewForm, EditForm). Using Mike's suggestion, would be a good idea to try appending the string to the page you have generated or navigate a user to, in order to ensure that works.

=====

Further info on the IsDlg=1 error, with regards to page errors (Look for "Jashion's" reply
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_winother-mso_o365b/using-isdlg-with-pages/286f324c-3054-4d7c-8ae9-d928fd2e1b17

=====

Additional info on how to use "SP.UI.ModalDialog" to call an HTML page, in case it's not practical to use a Web Part page. It may help, but I have not tried the code on this link:

[How to use SP.UI.ModalDialog on plain old HTML page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184540/how-to-use-sp-ui-modaldialog-on-plain-old-html-page)